# Programatically opening web page given unexpected results

Tags: python, html, ruby, nokogiri, urllib2

I'm trying to get information from this site:

http://www.gocrimson.com/sports/mbkb/2011-12/roster

If you look at that page in a browser, you see a nice `<table>` that contains all the player info, with the coach's info below it.

When I pull that page into a python program (using `urllib2`) or a ruby program (using `nokogiri`) the table is represented as a bunch of `div` elements.  I thought there might be some javascript running, so I disabled javascript on my browser and revisited the page.  It still loads up wit the `table`s in place.

If I use `Selenium` to pull in the page source, I do get the `table` format.

Any idea on why the page comes in with the divs?

Python:

```
page = urllib2.urlopen(url)
html = page.read()
```

`print html` output (I put one of the `div`s on the last line to draw attention to it.  That is a `tr` in the browser page. Shortened to stay under character limit):

```
'\t\t\t\r\n\t\t\r\n\t\t\r\n\t\t\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\t\t\t\t\r\n\r\n\r\n<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>\r\n<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//WAPFORUM//DTD XHTML Mobile 1.0//EN" "http://www.wapforum.org/DTD/xhtml-mobile10.dtd">\r\n<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head> 
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="application/xhtml+xml; charset=iso-8859-1"/> <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,minimum-scale=1.0,maximum-scale=1.0"/>\r\n<meta forua="true" http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="must-revalidate" />\r\n<meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache, must-revalidate" />\r\n        
<title>The Official Website of Harvard University Athletics:  Harvard Athletics - GoCrimson.com  : Men\'s Basketball - 2011-12 Roster </title>\r\n<link rel="stylesheet" href="/info/mobile/mobile.css" type="text/css"></link>\r\n<link rel="stylesheet" href="/mobile-overwrite.css" type="text/css"></link>\r\n</head>\r\n
<body class="classic">\r\n\r\n\r\n\t<strong><a href="/landing/index">News</a></strong>\r\n | \r\n\t<a href="/landing/index?c=scores">Scores</a>\r\n<br /><br />\r\n\r\n<p class="goBack-link"><a href="javascript:history.go(-1)"><<< Back</a></p>\r\n\r\n\r\n<div class="roster ">\r\n\t\t\t<div class="title">Men\'s Basketball - 2011-12 Roster</div>\r\n\t\t<div class="table">\r\n\t\t<div class="titles">\r\n\t\t\t
<div class="number">No.</div>\r\n\t\t\t<div class="name">Name</div>\r\n\t\t\t<div class="positions">Position</div>\r\n\t\t</div>\r\n\t\t\r\n\t\t\t\t\t<div class="item  even  clearfix">\r\n\t\t\t\t<div class="data">\r\n\t\t\t\t\t<div class="number">\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t3\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t</div>\r\n\t\t\t\t\t<div class="name">
```

ruby:

```
doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open("http://www.google.com/search?q=doughnuts"))
doc.css('tr').each do |node|
  puts node.text
end
```

finds no `tr`s, but

```
doc.css('div').each do |node|
  puts node.text
end
```

finds the `div`s

Comment: Tyler, show us your code please, both Ruby and Python, you can't expect us to write your scripts from scratch and perhaps having different results. BTW the negative vote is not from me, i hate when people do that without giving a reason

Comment: Sorry 'bout that.  Updated with examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to get a `<table>` instead of `div`s by adding User-Agent headers. Specifically I pretended to be a known popular browser.

```
opener = urllib2.build_opener()
opener.addheaders = [('User-agent',
    ('Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_6_7) '
     'AppleWebKit/535.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) '
     'Chrome/13.0.782.13 Safari/535.1'))
]
response = opener.open('http://www.gocrimson.com/sports/mbkb/2011-12/roster')
print response.readlines() # divs are now a table
```